# Does NSUndoManager work on iPhone without shake gestures?

Tags: iphone, shake, nsundomanager

I have an app that uses the shake gesture for something else besides undo. I want to use NSUndoManager and all the examples and how-tos say I have to put the following line in my applicationDidFinishLaunching method.

```
application.applicationSupportsShakeToEdit = YES;
```

Is it possible to use NSUndoManager without supporting the shake to undo gesture?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. Create an Undo button, then:

```
- (IBAction)undoButtonPressed {
    [myUndoManager undo];
}
```